# Word VBA macro on parentheticals

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been using the following macro to pull out items in parenthesis to comments in word:

```
'
' CommentBubble Macro
'
'
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
searchtext = "\(*\)"

With myRange.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    Do While .Execute(findText:=searchtext, Forward:=True) = True
      If Len(myRange.Text) > 4 Then
        ActiveDocument.Comments.Add myRange, myRange.Text
        myRange.Text = ""
      End If
    Loop
 End With
End Sub
```

The reason I have the length of the text be > 4 is because these are legal documents and I don't want to isolate strings that have things like "in the following conditions: (i) condition 1, (ii) condition 2, etc."

However, here is a snippet of text for which the above code breaks:

```
This is sample text (with some additional text) that does stuff (with more stuff) and represents 39.4% of shares on the effective date (before giving effect, with some conditions such as ( some stuff (i) and some stuff (ii) with final stuff) and more final stuff) which is subject to  (some conditions here) and conclude here.
```

If you run this you will get the following result:

```
This is sample text  that does stuff  and represents 39.4% of shares on the effective date  and some stuff (ii) with final stuff) and more final stuff) which is subject to   and conclude here.
```

As you can see the nested parenthesis cause some trouble. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You could follow up with a loop that finds double spaces and replaces them with a single space.

Comment: Exactly what is the trouble you wish to eliminate.  What are your rules for dealing with nested parentheses.  It looks like you would be better off with a method that moves the end of the range until it finds a ( or ).  If it finds ( when expecting ) then recursively call the method.

Comment: I want to move everything within the outermost parenthesis to a comment. If there are parenthesis within parenthesis that’s still just one comment.

Comment: Then you can use cset in a non recursive method.

Comment: I think it’s more complicated than that as you can have parenthesis within parenthesis.

Comment: I tried a few tests with the logic `"\(*\(\)"`, which sometimes worked, but I couldn't find a  100% solution. My idea would be to enumerate the first parenthesis, check if a "(" comes between it and the next ")", if, yes, then move to the next ")", etc. If the code hits a carriage return, then move back to the last ")". The space between the first "(" and the last ")" before the carriage return would be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match parentheses which in Word is a difficult and thankless task as Word only sees opening and closing parentheses as individual characters and not automatically matched by word.  The code below finds matching parentheses, eliminates trailing spaces, habdles the case of no parentheses being present, and errors out if you have unbalanced errors.  I've left in debugging statements so that you can uncomment them to see what is happening.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ttest()

    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
    myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
    
    
    Set myRange = NextParenRange(myRange)
    
    Do Until myRange Is Nothing
    
        DoEvents
        
        Debug.Print myRange.Text
        Dim myDupRange As Word.Range
        Set myDupRange = myRange.Duplicate
        myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        If myDupRange.Characters.Last.Next.Text = " " Then myDupRange.MoveEnd Count:=1
        myDupRange.Delete
        Set myRange = NextParenRange(myRange)
        
    
    Loop
    
End Sub

Public Function NextParenRange(ByVal ipRange As Word.Range) As Word.Range

    Const OpenP As String = "("
    Const CloseP As String = ")"
    
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Set myRange = ipRange.Duplicate
    
    'If myRange.Start <> myRange.End Then myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
    
    'exit if no parentheses exist
    'Debug.Print myRange.Start
    If myRange.MoveUntil(cset:=OpenP) = 0 Then
    
        Set NextParenRange = Nothing
        Exit Function
        
        
    Else
    
        'Debug.Print myRange.Start
        Dim myParenCount As Long
        myParenCount = 1
        myRange.MoveEnd Count:=1

    End If
    
    
    Do Until myParenCount = 0
    
        ' allows VBA to respond to a break key press
        DoEvents
        
        ' if we run out of parentheses before we get back to zero then flag an error
        If myRange.MoveEndUntil(cset:=OpenP & CloseP) = 0 Then
        
            VBA.Err.Raise 17, "Unbalanced parentheses in document"
            
            
        End If
        
        myRange.MoveEnd Count:=1
        'Debug.Print myRange.Characters.Last.Text
        'Debug.Print myRange.Characters.Last.Next.Text
        myParenCount = myParenCount + IIf(myRange.Characters.Last.Text = OpenP, 1, -1)
        
    
    Loop
    
    Set NextParenRange = myRange.Duplicate
    
End Function
```

Comment: nice solution (y)

Comment: Pretty neat, thank you!

Comment: @freeflow: Any suggestions how to change your code to work with a specific selection only? I changed `Set myRange = Selection.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)` but that doesn't seem enough.

Comment: You will need to do two things.  Change 'Set myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)' to 'Set myRange=selection.Range'.  You will also need to capture the end of myrange in a seperate variable and then in the do until loop test that the current start of the range is not more than the saved end of the range.  e.g. something like 'Do until myRange.start>=mySavedEnd'